# I will create a program Check stock with barcode, What do I need to learn

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, database

i will create a program check stock with barcode and database

what do i need to learn

What language should I use to development. And Should I use a database where.

c/c++, java, Visual C# not experience but pretty

spec
check in, check out and check amount in stock

Thank

sorry for grammar

Comment: What's wrong with Excel (or some other spreadsheet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of those languages will work. Most Barcode scanners are serial (RS-232), so you need to have the ability to connect through your language.  I would suggest C# on a windows platform because the .NET platform has a well-defined serial port.  Also, GUIs are pretty easy to implement.

As far as a database, you could start with a simple text database.  This is basically a file where each line is an item.  Make your interface to this clear, so if you need a full database later, you can easily switch them out.

Good luck